# How do I capture (in Fiddler) the HTTP requests issued by Nancy.Testing.Browser

Tags: unit-testing, fiddler, nancy

I have the following NancyFX unit test.

```
var browser = new Browser(new UnitTestBootstrapper());
var response = browser.Post("/login", with =>
    {
        with.FormValue("UserName", userName);
        with.FormValue("Password", password);
    });

response.ShouldHaveRedirectedTo("/home");
```

You can see that I use an instance of `Nancy.Testing.Browser` to POST some form values. I would like to capture this Http request in Fiddler but I am not sure how to set-up the Browser (a proxy perhaps?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because they never hit the network; that's the whole point of the browser class - to give you end to end testing without the performance hit/configuration issues of having to use hosting/http/networking/browser rendering.

If you want to go via the networking stack then use something like Selenium, or spin up a self host and poke it with EasyHttp or manually with HttpClient.